# Windows BSOD when all cpu cores enabled

Tags: windows, cpu, bsod, multi-core

I'm getting a blue screen "A clock interrupt was not received on a secondary processor within the allocated time interval", just a few seconds after the Windows desktop is loaded.  (For reference, this is [BugCheck  0x101: CLOCK_WATCHDOG_TIMEOUT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ff557211(v=vs.85).aspx).)

- My CPU is a Core i7 Extreme 975 and the BIOS is up to date.
- My motherboard is a Gigabyte EX58-UD5.
- My OS is Windows Server 2008 R2 (which I'm using as a Workstation).

For the moment, I disabled one core (out of four) on the BIOS settings and my computer is working well.
But I would like to use all the cores available in my CPU, with Windows.

I think it is not related to an hardware problem, because Ubuntu (Live CD) is working on my computer with all cores enabled.

I'm **NOT** using Hyper-V or any other roles.

Comment: Did this EVER work?  You mention your BIOS twice, but what kind of motherboard?

Comment: I'm always getting a BSOD.
My motherboard is a Gigabyte EX58-UD5.

Comment: Has Windows ever worked? Is this a new install or an old install that has suddenly broken?

Comment: Windows works only with 3 cores.
It always crashes with 4 cores.
It is a new install. Before I updated my BIOS, Windows (with all the 4 cores enabled) was crashing  before loading the desktop.

Comment: Hardware problems sometimes only exhibit for particular operating systems.  Can you select which core is disabled?

Comment: Is it at all possible to test the CPU in another computer, or test your computer with an alternate CPU?  I know you tried Ubuntu, but I would make 100% sure that it's not the CPU first (it's possible Ubuntu doesn't use a specific hardware feature that may be damaged in that particular core).  So long as your BIOS is up to date, and you experience no other hardware issues, keep your primary focus on the CPU.  You may also be able to bring it to a local computer shop and have them test the processor for you, if you don't have any pin-compatible ones.

Comment: Another thing to doublecheck, particularly if this is a home build, is that the motherboard supports that particular CPU model.

Comment: Can you select which core is disabled? No, I can't. Unfortunately, on the BIOS settings, it is only possible to select the number of core enabled. is that the motherboard supports that particular CPU model. The motherboard was designed specifically for Core i7. In this [forum](http://www.brakstar.com/forum/braktopic_5185.html), they recommend to set the page file size manually for those who have this trouble. I have tested this method. In fact, before I tested this method, when the page file size was defined automatically, Windows was crashing during the startup (just after the loading screen)

Comment: I did not install Hyper-V or any other roles,
as I'm using Windows Server 2008 R2 as a Workstation OS.

Comment: It might still be worth trying the hotfix JdeBP refers to.  It isn't clear whether or not it will install on a non hyper-V system, but it won't do any harm.

Answer (score 4):

You have a "Nehalem" microarchitecture Intel CPU, you have Windows Server 2008 R2, and you haven't installed the hotfix.

### Further reading

#### Microsoft blames Intel.

- Ben Armstrong (2009-10-16). [*Hyper-V Hotfix for "0x00000101 - CLOCK_WATCHDOG_TIMEOUT" on Nehalem systems*](https://web.archive.org/web/20100618064131/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/virtual_pc_guy/archive/2009/10/16/hyper-v-hotfix-for-0x00000101-clock-watchdog-timeout-on-nehalem-systems.aspx).  MSDN.
- Microsoft corporation (2010-11-23). [*Stop error message on a Windows Server 2008 R2-based computer that has the Hyper-V role installed and that uses one or more Intel CPUs that are code-named Nehalem: "0x00000101 - CLOCK_WATCHDOG_TIMEOUT"*](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/975530). MSKB 975530.

#### Intel blames Microsoft.

- Intel corporation (2010-07-12). [*Stop Code 0x00000101, CLOCK_WATCHDOG_TIMEOUT Error in Windows with Hyper-V*](https://web.archive.org/web/20120104180448/http://www.intel.com/support/motherboards/server/s5520sc/sb/CS-031717.htm).  CS-031717.

#### Always check the doco provided by the manufacturer *before* coming to SuperUser.

- Microsoft corporation (2011-10-26). [*Hyper-V Update List for Windows Server 2008 R2*](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/1349.hyper-v-2008-r2-update-list.aspx).

Comment: The Hyper-V role is not installed by default.  Anonymous, did you install Hyper-V?

Comment: The second MS link above says this in the workaround section: "You can disable the Advance Configuration and Power Interface (ACPI) C-states by using a BIOS firmware option on the computer. If the firmware does not include this option, a software workaround is available. You can disable the ACPI C2-state and C3-state by setting a registry key." Though everything is in the context of hyper-v, this appears to be a ACPI power save issue (?)

Comment: Also this linux bug listing might be old news, but possibly relevant: "This bug has not been visible until Nehalem, which advertises
a CPU-C2 worst case exit latency on servers of 205usec.
That (incorrect) figure is being used by BIOS writers
on mobile Nehalem systems for the AC configuration.
Thus, Linux ignores C2 leaving just C1, which is
saves less power, and also impacts performance
by preventing the use of turbo mode." ( see: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/516325 )